# How to add a custom package in Tectonic

Tags: packages, tectonic

I've written a `.sty` file, named `creator.sty`. When I was using TexLive, there is a folder where all `.sty` files are stored. I'm now changing to Tectonic, and I cannot find such a folder, and I don't want to put `creator.sty` into every project I develop. Is their any way to install a custom package by Tectonic?

Comment: I personally put a symbolic link  in the each project to a more global `perso.sty`

Comment: That's a pretty solution, ty.